# MBP 13" 2020 x64 starts unbelievably slow (10 mins for restart)

Tags: startup, big-sur

I received a new MBP 13" 2020 x64 in January this year. It was already updated to Big Sur (Currently 11.3 is installed). Since the beginning, it seems to have issues when starting up. E.g. I removed some Canon tools and rebooted the MBP and it took me way more then 10 minutes to restart. The login screen won't recognize Bluetooth devices like my Magic Mouse or Magic Keyboard directly. It takes some time but also not all keystrokes are recognized (like 3 out of 8). So it is impossible to type my password with it.

Once it is in operational mode, it works almost flawlessly. This is why i just log out instead of turning the MBP off. But this shouldn't be the case.

My last MBP 13" 2019 and 2016 worked like a charm. No issues at all.

I found some resources stating resetting the NVRAM or SMC might help, but they didn't or I did not reset them properly.

Does someone here has the same issues?

Comment: Did you receive this MBP new with Big Sur pre-installed or was this a refurb with Big Sur installed? I ask because you mention "I removed some Canon tools" leading me to believe that this is **not** a new machine.

Comment: There may be better/faster options than the following but if nothing else is suggested can you install macOS to a hard drive and see if the problem persists? This would rule out a hardware issue. You could also try to repair the disk in disk utility preferably in recovery mode and last but not least a clean install should solve the problem if it is software related.

Comment: You can download Etrecheck and share in your thirst post the report text  (by a link pastebin maybe) .

Comment: @agarza This was a brand new one preinstalled with Big Sur. I was just recently uninstalling them because I exchanged my 1300D with a new M50 and tried to "reinstall" the Webcam Utility Tool because it didn't recognize my M50 out of the box. So I uninstalled them and had to reboot the system. Then I ran into the issue that the startup ist sooooooo slow.

Comment: As per @X_841 suggestion, you need to isolate the problem to software or hardware. If you have an extra drive, install an OS on it and boot from it to see how the MBP behaves.

Comment: Okay, so my company seems to set up some security policies to prohibit booting from external drive. Are there some other ideas to check the HW?